# Limit without L'Hospital rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> The value of $$\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}y \ln\bigg(\frac{\sin(x+1/y)}{\sin x}\bigg), x\in \bigg(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg)$$

Try: Put $\displaystyle y=\frac{1}{z}$

So $$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\ln\bigg(\frac{\sin(x+z)}{\sin x}\bigg)\cdot \frac{1}{z}$$

$$ = \lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(\sin (x+z))-\ln(\sin x)}{z}$$

Using L'Hospital rule

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos(x+z)}{\sin (x+z)}=\cot x$$

Could some help me? How can I solve without L'Hospital rule? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\displaystyle\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}y \ln\bigg(\frac{\sin(x+1/y)}{\sin x}\bigg)=\displaystyle\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}y \ln\bigg(\frac{\sin(x)\cos(1/y)+\cos(x)\sin(1/y)}{\sin x}\bigg)\\=\displaystyle\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}y \ln\bigg(\cos(1/y)+\cot(x)\sin(1/y)\bigg)\\=\displaystyle\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}y \ln\bigg(1+\big[\cos(1/y)+\cot(x)\sin(1/y)-1\big]\bigg)$

Since $\cos(1/y)+\cot(x)\sin(1/y)-1\to0$ as $y\to\infty$, using the standard limit $\displaystyle\lim_{m\to0}\frac{\ln(1+m)}{m}=1$, we get

$=\displaystyle\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}y\big(\cos(1/y)+\cot(x)\sin(1/y)-1\big)\\=\displaystyle\lim_{z\to0^+}\frac{\cos z-1}z+\cot(x)\cdot\lim_{z\to0^+}\frac{\sin z}z$

Comment: This is how I would have answered but I guess I was late. +1

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(\sin (x+z))-\ln(\sin x)}{z}$ is precisely the derivative of $\ln(\sin x)$ for $x\in\left(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$using limits.

Comment: Using the derivative is precisely using L'Hôpital's rule. Which the OP is requesting not to do.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: You've got to use L'Hopital's rule at some stage.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: Not exactly (L'Hospital's Rule involves differentiation followed by a limit operation) but if one forbids L'Hospital's Rule then the implicit intention is to forbid derivatives as well.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use L'Hospital's Rule at some stage. Just use basic limit laws and you get the desired answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Differentiation with limits uses L'Hopital rule implicitly in certain cases. How will one evaluate using just basic limit laws ? Can you elaborate.

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule uses derivatives but one does not need L'Hospital's Rule to evaluate derivatives otherwise the whole thing will become circular. Here the key is to use $\dfrac{\log t} {t-1}\to 1$ as $t\to 1$. See this idea used in answer from Shubham Johri.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: At first glance I overlooked it. I see it know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Beside the simple solution given by Yadati Kiran, you could use Taylor series
$$\frac{\sin(x+z)}{\sin (x)}=\cot (x) \sin (z)+\cos (z)$$ Now, using the classical expansion of $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ you then have
$$\cot (x) \sin (z)+\cos (z)=1+z \cot (x)-\frac{z^2}{2}+O\left(z^3\right)$$ Continue with the logarithm to get 
$$\log (\cot (x) \sin (z)+\cos (z))=z \cot (x)-\frac{1}{2} z^2 \left(\cot ^2(x)+1\right)+O\left(z^3\right)$$
$$\frac 1 z \log (\cot (x) \sin (z)+\cos (z))= \cot (x)-\frac{1}{2} z \left(\cot ^2(x)+1\right)+O\left(z^2\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution, more of a question.

I get to

1)$\log \left ( \cos (1/y) +\frac{\sin (1/y)}{1/y}\frac{\cot x}{y}\right )^y.$

$y \rightarrow \infty : $

Known:

2) $\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} \log (1+(\cot x)/y)^y= \cot x$.

(Recall $\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}(1+a/y)^y= e^a$, $a$ real.)

Is there a fairly straightforward way to get from 1)to 2) using limit manipulations ?

Could not come up with a solution.

Thanks

Comment: The way is not fairly straightforward but not that difficult either. Use the fact that if $f(y) >0$ and $y(f(y)-1) \to 0$ as $y\to\infty $ then $\{f(y)\} ^y\to 1$ as $y\to \infty$ (prove this!). Use $$f(y) =\dfrac{\cos(1/y)+\sin(1/y)\cot x} {1+\dfrac{\cot x} {y}} $$ and show that $y(f(y) - 1)\to 0$ as $y\to\infty $.

Comment: Paramand.Thanks a lot. I'll go through your suggestions. Was  intrigued by [(cos 1/y)^y](1+[(cos (1/y))^{-1}]sin(1/y)(1/y)^{-1}[(cos x)/y])^y, By multiplication rule can consider lim (cos 1/y)^y×lim(1+A(y)(cos x)/y)^y, where lim A(y)=1,  could not handle this second limit .